# How should PostgreSQL be configured for this setup?

Tags: performance, postgresql

I would like to tweak my PostgreSQL server but even after reading a few tutorials online I am not getting good performance out of the database.

I've got a server with the following specs:

- Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
- Intel CPU E5-2670 v2 @ 2.50 GHz
- 64-bit Operating System
- 512 GB RAM
- PostgreSQL 9.3

I would like to use postgres as a data storage / aggregation system for the following tasks:

- Read data from various data sources (mostly flat files) (volumes between 100GB and 1TB)
- Pre-process / clean data
- Aggregate data
- Feed aggregated or sampled data into R or python for modelling
- Up to 10 concurrent users only

This means, I do not really care about the following:

- Update speads (I only bulk-load data)
- Failure resistance (in the unlikely event that things break, I can always reload everything from my input files)

Currently, load speeds are fine, but creating indexes and aggregating data takes very long and barely uses any memory.

Here is my current postgres.config: http://pastebin.com/KpSi2zSd

Comment: You can set `affectieve_cache_size` to a higher value, maybe 300...400 GB. And you can lower max_connections. And: is there any good reason to use Windows?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your suggestions, I did increase those but effective_cache_size only affects the planner, right? So it wouldn't make a difference for stuff like indexing, sorting or aggregating if I understand correctly? The reason I use Windows is because the server is also used for other services and I don't want to mess with a system that's otherwise running well.

Comment: *only* affects the planner ... What else should it affect? { random_page_cost, work_mem, effective_cache_size} are the basic tuning knobs for query generation -->> plan selection. BTW: *indexing* does not exist. The planner is free to choose whether to *use* an index.

Comment: Well I'm trying to get postgres to aggregate more quickly, this is not a problem with the planner (assuming this needs a full table abandoned anyway). By indexing I mean creating an index, which takes a lot of time (and currently doesn't use a lot of memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the obvious step here is to increase the work_mem and maintenance_work_mem considerably, with the fine detail being "how much"?

If you have control over how many aggregation queries and/or index creations are running at a time then you can be pretty aggressive with these, but you face the risk that with 10 concurrent users and a 30GB setting you could be putting your server under memory pressure.

It would really benefit you to get some execution plans for the slow running queries, as they will tell you that you need so-much memory for "Sort Method: external merge Disk" for example, and you can then adjust your settings while keeping an eye on the total memory usage on the server.

I wouldn't rule out that you have to re-jig your loads so that the most resource intensive run on their own, while less resource intensive operations run at the same time.

However, I think at the moment you are lacking some of the hard metrics that will let you make a good choice on memory allocation.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer. I wanted to check the performance difference after increasing work_mem, but with everything above 1GB the service won't start. The log just says `FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command` which is not really enlightening. Do you know where to look for the problem?

Comment: @phildeutsch I would pop a new question on the site for that one. Could be a Windows/PostgreSQL memory quirk.